# Scala project does not automatically build in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, build-process

I copied the examples folder from scala-2.7.7.final-devel-docs to the src folder of a scala project.

But the source files will not compiled unless I change them manually. "Project/Build automatically" is checked.

I'm using the Scala Eclipse Plugin 2.7.7-final

How can I achieve that this works like in java projects?

Comment: How did you copy those files? Did you create a Scala project for them?

Comment: First I created a scala project, after that using in explorer copy and in eclipse paste, after that I did a refresh.

Comment: Does the project build correctly if you explicitly invoke the project build action?

Comment: @Miles Sabin No, I tried build working set also, I did update to eclipse 3.5.1 no effect.

Comment: OK, could you open a ticket in Trac with you .project and .classpath files attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Miles Sabin I found the answer while ensuring not to open a duplicate ticket.
This behaviour is a known bug. And indeed I had files with errors in this project.

http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/683